# EclipseLink Query Caching Issue

Tags: caching, eclipselink

I am working with EclipseLink Query Caching in very complex system.

To monitor the logs, I have enable Query Monitor and Performance Monitor logs by adding below properties in `Persistence.xml`:

```
!property name="eclipselink.profiler" value="QueryMonitor" />
!property name="eclipselink.profiler" value="PerformanceMonitor" />
```

I got the below log in query monitor logs for one of the Named Query(which returns single result):

```
com.xxx.yyy.session.jpa.UserInfoEntity-UserInfo.nameSearch  0   4
```

Then I have enabled query caching by adding below property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

After that I got the same Query monitor log again without any changes:

```
com.xxx.yyy.session.jpa.UserInfoEntity-UserInfo.nameSearch  0   4
```

then I have added following hints in "UserInfoEntity-UserInfo.nameSearch" (Named Query) to enable the query cache:

```
hints={@QueryHint(name="eclipselink.refresh", value="true"), 
@QueryHint(name="eclipselink.cache-usage", value="CheckCacheThenDatabase")
```

After that in Query Monitor logs the log for "UserInfoEntity-UserInfo.nameSearch" query got disappear.

Can someone tell me, am I doing the right configuration to make the Named-Query cachable?

If so, how can I identify that query got cached or not? If not, How can I configure it properly?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The property you have shown is "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" - a hibernate property yet you are using EclpseLink.  see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache

Comment: Thanks Chris...Actually I tried below options also but nothing got changed for the Named Query                                               @Hint(name="eclipselink.query-results-cache", value="true")
@Hint(name="eclipselink.query-results-cache.size", value="500")                so my doubt is that how can I identify that Named Query got cached or not?

Comment: I asked same question here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1488333/#msg_1488333, but since no replay, I have to go to debug, stop code after first reading from db, modify db or disconnect from network and run same query.